# Struts2 jqGrid: How to send column value as parameter in edit scenario

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

```
               <sjg:gridColumn 
                name="id" 
                index="id" 
                title="id"
                key="true"
                hidden="true" 
                />
           <sjg:gridColumn 
                name="categoryId" 
                index="categoryId" 
                title="categoryId"
                hidden="true" 
                />
```

I have following columns in grid, i would like to send "categoryId" as parameter to edit action. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `editable: true` and `hidedlg: true` to the properties of the hidden column `categoryId`. Additionally you should add [editrules: { edithidden: false }](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules)

Comment: Thanks for answering question, but i am using editcell mode, and it is required to send "categoryId" as parameter whenever editing another cell in row. Currently only thing it sends is ID; which is key=true.

Comment: @user980912: It seems me very strange. What value has the `id`? Why you need to have two ids: `id` and `categoryId`? Why you need to have the both columns at all? The `id` of the row (the id of `<tr>`) could already has the information which you need. The value of the rowid can be `id`+'_'+`categoryId` for example. You can easy strip such value on the server side in two parts and use as you need.

Comment: thanks that did the trick... actually my grid is base of complex database view, which need to update several tables...

Comment: @user980912: You are welcome! It's a standard problem. The usage on combined key can solve it. Don't forget to remove `id` and `categoryId` columns from the grid definition if you want have the columns always hidden. You don't need to have hidden `<td>` elements in every row of the grid if you have already the same information as the `id` attribute of the `<tr>` element.